# Custom sort order for loaded collection?

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, product-collection, sorting

I have a product collection created by Magento for the category product list.

I then pass some information about this collection to an external method that returns the entity IDs in a specific sort order.

Now I'd like to re-order the product collection according to the order of the entity IDs, which is completely random and does not follow any conceivable logic.

What would the best approach be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your product collection is stored in the variable `$productCollection` and your list of a specific ordered entity IDs are in the array `$entityIdsOrder`.

Below is how you re-order your product collection according to a specific order of the entity IDs.

```
$productCollection->getSelect()
->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('FIELD(e.entity_id, ' . implode(',', $entityIdsOrder).')'));
```